# ¿Cómo enviar datos en Java?

Tags: java, poo, netbeans

Lo que pasa es que necesito crear un arreglo cuando de click sobre el botón "Crear", para después ir guardando números dentro de ese mismo arreglo cada que presione el botón "Agregar" pero no encuentro manera de poder usar el arreglo dentro del evento del otro botón.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Las variables pueden ser públicas o privadas, si declaras el arreglo dentro del boton  "btnCrear" ese mismo arreglo no existira en "btnAgregar". Para que pueda existir para toda la clase, debes instanciarlo fuera del metodo que te genera NetBeans con el boton, eso lo logras solo cambiando el lugar donde creas el arreglo "numeros". Para eviatar inicializar el arreglo cada vez que precionen el boton, puedes usar un booleano de validación:

```
int numeros[]; //Instanciamos el arreglo
public boolean primerIngreso = true;  //Iniciamos la bandera que nos dira si es el primer ingreso del usuario (O primer clic)
private void btnCrear(){
  if(primerIngreso){  // si es su primer ingreso, que lo inicialice
     numeros = new int [10];
     primerIngreso = false;  // como ya ingreso, pasamos la bandera a falso para que la siguiente vez no se cumpla la validación y no lo inicie de nuevo
  }
}
```

De ese modo, el resto del código ya reconocera el arreglo para su uso. Tomar en cuenta que si el arreglo no ha pasado por la inicialización (Es decir, que el usuario no ha precionado el boton) al intentar usarlo en otro metodo el programa se truncara